# org.w3c.dom.Element setAttribute("xlink:href", filename)

Tags: java, dom, svg

I have this Java method trying to change an image in a org.w3c.dom.Document.

```
Element element = (Element)svgDoc.getElementById("SVGimage");
    element.setAttribute("width", "100");
    element.setAttribute("xlink:href", filename); 
    svgCanvas.setDocument(svgDoc);
```

the corresponding SVG file has this line:

```
<image id="SVGimage"  x="100" y="100" height="200" width="200" xlink:href="VAGUE.svg"/>
```

The 'width' changes correctly, the image stays idle.

Comment: You must call setAttributeNS to set something in the xlink namespace.

Comment: I did try: element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", filename) it has no effect.

Comment: The correct call is: element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", filename); It works now. Thks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct call is:

```
 element.setAttributeNS("w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", filename);
```

Comment: to whom it may concern: i have to use "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink". (EDIT; the link gets shortened by stackoverflows visuals... "http  : // www." without the spaces as a prefix to what you can see)